# Multiple branch pull requests behavior

Tags: git, azure-devops

So this is a theoretical question:

You have a development branch.
Peter, Thomas and Karla branch off and create their feature branches.

They all rebase their finished features to the latest development branch and create pull requests at the same time.

Of course they are processed in the order they actually came in (Peter, Thomas, Karla). But they all have the rebase of the development branch before anyone had their pull request fullfilled.

What will happen?

I guess that only the first person's (Peter) pull request will go through since the others would have to rebase the updated development branch again?

This would repeat until everyone has their pull request finished?

What will the code review pages look like? Do they know that there are currently three outstanding pull requests that maybe have to rebase/remerge again? Will they update themselves and show an error that it can't be merged into development once the first person's pull request is fullfilled?

Comment: What code review system are you using?  That makes a big difference here, and honestly the best thing to do is make a small project and test it yourself.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Team Services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the pull requests will show conflicts until the target branch is actually updated (by merging one of the outstanding PRs or by pushing directly to the target branch).

As soon as one of the PRs is merged, the others will show conflicts.

Comment: So the pull request will automatic fail and they will have to rebase and create another one, correct?

Comment: The PR's can't be merged until their branches are rebased. new PR's are not needed. A PR is not something that can fail, so I'm not sure what you mean by "automatically fail".

Comment: Oh okay. In VSTS the Pull Request is automatically merged once a fixed number of reviewers stated its okay. So I guess this automatic merging won't happen even if all reviewers stated okay, since the PR has to rebase again. So I thought the request would fail like it fails for example when the automatic build has errors.